# How can I use an easing with scrolltop using jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to animate this back to top icon with an easing. Instead it simply jumps to the top of the page. What am I missing?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
        $("#back-to-top").fadeIn(200);
    } else{
        $("#back-to-top").fadeOut(200);
    }
});

$('#back-to-top, .back-to-top').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop:0
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        easing: "easeInOutExpo"
    });
});
```

Comment: paste your code with html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeEvj/3/)

Okay this was confusing.

Your original code works.

It just required including jQuery UI library also for the easing you're using is not a part of the regular jQuery library.

```
$('button').click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:0 }, 
        {
            duration: 1200,
            easing: "easeInOutExpo"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only supported easing types in jQuery are the default which is `swing` and then `linear`. If you want to use something like `easeInOutExpo` then you need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

This code will use `linear` easing. You can switch it to `swing` to see the difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3qqN/

```
$('#back-to-top, .back-to-top').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate(
        { scrollTop: 0 },
        {
            duration: 1200,
            easing: 'linear'
            // try using 'swing' too
            // 'easeInOutExpo' is supported with jQuery UI
        }
    });
});
```

`easeInOutExpo` is not part of jQuery. It is a part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) - is jQuery UI included and loaded when you run your code?

Comment: I want a smooth scroll to the top of the page rather than an anchor jump

Comment: @Italy; it doesn't follow the easeInOutExpo path (http://easings.net/#easeInOutExpo)

Comment: @Matthew yes jquery-ui is loaded

Comment: @alias51 Please upload your entire code to jsFiddle so e can take a look

Comment: Can you verify that the easing type `'linear'` works? If it does, then the problem must be with jQuery UI.